# VBA regex vs other regexes - I don't understand why it's doing that?

Tags: regex, vba

So, I have been working with js previously and I have some regexes that I have tested with regexr and regex101 and they work great. However, when I decided to use that expression for VBA, it stopped working properly.

The original js regex:

`(?:    AT FOLLOWING LOCATION[ \w]+\n)?(?: +FX -[\s\S]*?)((?:MP[ ]+[\d.\w]+[ -]+?[\w\b .\/]+)(?:[ -]+[\w\b .\/]+$)?)[\s\S]*?(?:\d+\.+\d\d[\) ]+(?:FT.? *\n|IN.? *\n)|USE X AT MP +\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|(?=\n {4}\w)|(?=\n {2}\()|$)`

For the sake of our discussion, let's use the following as a match sample:

```
    FX - LALALA:
           MP  123 - TEST - TESTER WORLD
       NOTICE THAT I AM HERE TOO`
```

The vba regex initially tested was the same, and it did not work. So I started looking further and tested the chunks one at a time, and noted that the problem seems to lie in `\n`. For the example above, it would be `(?:[ -]+[\w\b .\/]+$)?` that failed and I tested `[ -]+[\w\b .\/]+` and it worked, while `[ -]+[\w\b .\/]+\n` did not (gim flags were enabled). What I don't understand is, why did it work with js and other algorithms - it looks like \n is legal with vba Regex?

And, more importantly, other than understanding why it behaves how it did, what would be the best ways to make it work?

---

Edit 1:

Based on comments, I have changed `\n` to `[\r\n]+` instead. With that, it worked with my tester strings that uses `vbCrLf` as line breaks. However, when applying to the actual document, it no longer worked. It appears that the text read from the document shows up as an up arrow when being displayed through immediate via `debug.print()`. I tried highlighting it but when I do so, it changes from an up arrow to a blank square (like one of those unreadable characters). I tried copying the document text over to Notepad++ so that I can read the symbols better, and it appears that they are CrLf, but I don't know if clipboard changed anything or not. The symbol shown in word shows it as a soft return instead of a hard return. What am I missing still?

Comment: Sorry, after some additional testing, it wasn't zero length strings, it was the \n it seems like? I updated the information.

Comment: Are you sure you have `\n` newline? Try replacing all `\n` with `\r` since the CR symbol is used as a newline inside various textboxes or fields.

Comment: So, if I use \r for the sub expression of [ -]+[\w\b .\/]+[\r\n]+ it works, but it still doesn't match when I run it for the lines. When I am doing testing, I separated the test string by vbCrLf and it matched as intended, but when I run it on the paragraphs, it stopped working. What seems strange to me is, there was a \n or []\r\n]+ that I used in the prior portion, and it worked (?:    AT FOLLOWING LOCATION[ \w]+[\r\n]+)?. But when I applied it to the paragraph text, it doesn't work. They both looked like soft returns, so why would it match for statement 1 and not statement 2???